# Undefined index: selected (PHP)

Tags: php, html

i'm gettimg this error on my page while modifying checkbox : **Notice: Undefined index: selected in**....[my file location]
anyone know what had gone wrong?

this is part of my script:

```
 <?php
        if(!empty($konfirm))
        {
          foreach ($konfirm as $konfirm) { ?>
        <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><?php if ($konfirm['selected']) { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?php echo $konfirm['id']; ?>" checked="checked" />
            <?php } else { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?php echo $konfirm['id']; ?>" />
            <?php } ?></td>
```

am i missing something? Please give me your direction.. Tell me if my description wasn't clear enough. Thank You very much.

Comment: `$konfirm['selected']` is not set

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your variable `$konfirm` by declaring it as the "each" variable in your `foreach` statement. Rename this temporary variable to something else, and replace the name in the appropriate instances inside your loop iteration.

```
<?php
if (!empty($konfirm))
{
   foreach ($konfirm as $this_konfirm) { ?>
        <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><?php if ($this_konfirm['selected']) { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?php echo $this_konfirm['id']; ?>" checked="checked" />
            <?php } else { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?php echo $this_konfirm['id']; ?>" />
            <?php } ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the existence of the checkbox form post. It will be set if it is checked or not set if it is not checked on the form.

```
<?php if (isset($konfirm['selected'])) { ?>
```